# convert my type to string

Tags: c#, persian, persian-calendar

I have a class as:

```
public class PersianDate
{
    public int Year;
    public int Month;
    public int Day;
    public int Hour;
    public int Minute;
    public int Second;
    public string MonthName;
}
```

I want that if I convert it like here:

```
HTools.PersianDate pDate=new HTools.PersianDate();
string date = pDate.ToString();
```

And I want date to be:

> 1396-06-14T19:17:38

How can I do that?

Comment: Use string.Format?

Comment: Have you tried anything? override the `ToString`? Also have a look at `PersianCalendar` instead of creating your own

Comment: thank you so much,  and i wanted to have my own calendar, and I already knew about overriding methods,but didn't work overriding existing methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class PersianDate
{
    public int Year;
    public int Month;
    public int Day;
    public int Hour;
    public int Minute;
    public int Second;
    public string MonthName;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}T{3}:{4}:{5}",Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute,Second);
    }
}
```

Override `ToString()` method from `object` class to get the format you want.

[DotNetFiddle Example.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OL5tZP)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string that represent the object as a json you can use the "Newtonsift.Json" Nuget package:

```
PersianDate thing = new PersianDate();
//TODO: fill you thing with the data you need
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(thing);
```

If you want specific string - ovverride the ToString methods in your class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
     return $"{Year}-{Month}-{Day}T{Hour}:{Minute}:{Second}";
}
```

Comment: OP never said he wants to use JSON. You coud suggest him xml serialization, that would be equally pointless. btw, your `ToString()` will return format OP didn't ask for.

Comment: Well is not straight forward what he ask,
 I gave him couple of options. If you look at the title of the question it says: "convert my type to string". If you want to "convert" you type of object to string, serialization is the way to go. If you just want to implement a new ToString methods.. then option #2